# Stop WooCommerce redirecting wp-login.php and wp-admin to account pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-roles

With a plain-vanilla Wordpress install, a subscriber can access /wp-login.php, login and visit the dashboard.

I've found that after installing WooCommerce, if a subscriber is logged in and then tries to revisit the wp-admin or wp-login.php they are redirected to the my-account page set in the WooCommerce settings.

I wondered if there is anyway to remove this functionality as it isn't right for my site.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

***Solution***

I have found a solution and posted it on this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45048756/wordpress-login-page-redirecting-to-woocommerce-my-account-page-for-normal-users/48332692#48332692)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a way to achieve that for the "subscriber" user role:

```
// Conditional function code for 'subscriber' User Role
function is_subscriber_user(){
    if( current_user_can('subscriber') ) return true;
    else return false;
 }

// Redirect 'subscriber' User Role to the User edit prodile on WooCommerce's My Account
// So when he get looged or it register too
 add_filter('template_redirect', 'wp_subscriber_my_account_redirect' );
function wp_subscriber_my_account_redirect() {
    if( is_subscriber_user() && is_account_page() )
        wp_redirect( get_edit_profile_url( get_current_user_id() ) );
}

// Prevent automatic woocommerce redirection for 'subscriber' User Role 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_automatic_wizard_redirect', 'wc_subscriber_auto_redirect', 20, 1 );
function wc_subscriber_auto_redirect( $boolean ) {
    if( is_subscriber_user() )
        $prevent_access = true;
    return $boolean;
}

// Allow 'subscriber' User Role to  view the Dashboard
add_filter( 'woocommerce_prevent_admin_access', 'wc_subscriber_admin_access', 20, 1 );
function wc_subscriber_admin_access( $prevent_access ) {
    if( is_subscriber_user() )
        $prevent_access = false;

    return $prevent_access;
}

// Show admin bar for 'subscriber' User Role
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'wc_subscriber_show_admin_bar', 20, 1 );
function wc_subscriber_show_admin_bar( $show ) {
    if ( is_subscriber_user() )
        $show = true;
    return $show;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

Tested and works.

> If you want the "subscriber" user **to be redirected to the dashboard** instead of the edit profile, you just have to replace `get_edit_profile_url()` function by `get dashboard url()`…

Answer (score 1):

You can use WooCommerce hooks to redirect users with different roles, see docs: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

I Just Google 'woocommerce redirect subscribers' and your answer came in the first result :)

---

So you can solve your website's issue using the Woocommerce hook filter **woocommerce_login_redirect** to redirect to a desired page based on the user role.

```
function wc_custom_user_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {
// Get the first of all the roles assigned to the user
$role = $user->roles[0];
$dashboard = admin_url();
$myaccount = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );
if( $role == 'administrator' ) {
    //Redirect administrators to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
} elseif ( $role == 'shop-manager' ) {
    //Redirect shop managers to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
} elseif ( $role == 'editor' ) {
    //Redirect editors to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
} elseif ( $role == 'author' ) {
    //Redirect authors to the dashboard
    $redirect = $dashboard;
} elseif ( $role == 'customer' || $role == 'subscriber' ) {
    //Redirect customers and subscribers to the "My Account" page
    $redirect = $myaccount;
} else {
    //Redirect any other role to the previous visited page or, if not available, to the home
    $redirect = wp_get_referer() ? wp_get_referer() : home_url();
}
return $redirect;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_custom_user_redirect', 10, 2 );
```

See source: https://gist.github.com/lmartins/28186383883d7c5ec644

Comment: Thanks for this. I had also found this and doesn't work perversely. I've stepped through the code and the hook is never called as it is not a woocommerce login but a wordpress login!